# We have sequence of random variables $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$. Let $\eta=\inf\{n:X_n > X_0\}$. Find distribution $\eta$ and $E\eta$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

We have sequence of random variables $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ independent identity distributed with continuous cdf. Let $\eta=inf\{n:X_n > X_0\}$. Find distribution $\eta$ and $E\eta$.

Is my approach correct?
$$
\begin{split}
P(\eta = n)
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X_n > t \wedge X_0 \le t) dt \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X_n > t)P( X_0 \le t)dt \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_{X_0}(t)(1-F_{X_n}(t))dt
\end{split}
$$

Comment: No, it is not. You are calculating the probability that $X_n > X_0$, but it can happen that $n$ is not the first index in which this happens. The first equality is actually a $\le$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
P(\eta = n )
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P( X_1 \leq t \wedge X_2 \leq  t ....\wedge ... X_{n-1}  \leq t \wedge X_n > t | X_0 = t ) \cdot f_{X_0}(t) dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P( X_1  \leq t ) \cdot P( X_2  \leq t ) ... P( X_{n-1}   \leq t ) \cdot P( X_n > t ) \cdot f_{X_0}(t) dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (F_X(t))^{n-1} \cdot ( 1 - F_X(t) ) \cdot f_X(t) dt \\
\end{split}
$$

Using substitution
$$
\begin{split}
u = F_X(t)
\end{split}
$$
We get
$$
\begin{split}
P(\eta=n) = 1/(n(n+1)) \\
E[\eta] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot P(\eta=n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(n+1) = \infty
\end{split}
$$

Comment: You mean $\cdot$ instead of $*$?

Comment: right. I am new to writing equations on computer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**
Notice that it should hold $P[X_1 > X_0] = P[X_0 > X_1] = 1/2$. (Since the random variables are continuous, $P[X_i = X_j] = 0$ for $i \neq j$). This means $P[\eta = 1] = \frac12$. Can you generalize this reasoning?